# Write a java program that takes two integers n and m one the first line and four integers on the second line and multiplies them

Tags: java, arrays, bufferedreader

Write a program that takes input of integers N and M (separated by space) on first line, followed by an array of N integers on second line (separated by space) and then M more lines, each with an integer. For each of the of those ​*M*​ integers, output "True" (without quotes), if that number is present in the array N. Output "False" (without quotes) otherwise.

Constraints:
0 < N < 20,000

0 < M < 15,000

so far i have,

```
import java.io.*;

class Main
{
    static int arr[];
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String input = br.readLine();
        str="\\s+";
        while((str=input.readLine())!=null)
            String[] numberList = input.split("\\s+");
    }

    }
}
```

the intended input e.g

```
4 2
99 12 10 23
23
25
```

and output:

```
Output:
True
False
```

and the explanation is as follows

Explanation: An array of size 4 is taken, followed by 2 lines. 23 outputs True, since 23 is present in above array. 25 outputs False because it was not in the array of N numbers.

however i am having some problems with the being able to read in from multiple lines and changing it to arrays of int.

Any help guys?

Cheers

****UPDATE******

so the new code i have now is

```
/* package whatever; // don't place package name! */

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class Main
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {

        BufferedReader stdin = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)); 
        String line;
           if ((line = stdin.readLine()) != null) { 
            String[] input = line.split("\\s+"); 
            for(int i=0;i<input.length;i++){
                System.out.println(input[i]);
            }
           // break;
        } 

    }


}
```

but the loop keeps getting stuck and wont exit. I cant add a trivial character to the end of the string to make it exit. any suggestions?/

Comment: Please, write less in the title...

Comment: Hint: since you know the number of array elements (4 in your example) you can create an array with that length (or use a list). Then there's `Integer.parseInt("someNumber")`... - And you also know the number of lines to read: 1 header line with the numbers N and M, 1 array line with N elements and M more lines.

Comment: 'however i am having some problems with the being able to read in from multiple lines and changing it to arrays of int.' - where are you stuck? have you succeded in getting all the input from the user as String?

Comment: The java.util.Scanner class seems perfect for the reading part.

Comment: no thats where my problem is, i cant seem to get the whole two lines of numbers via a string!

Comment: @JonnySmyth - read about the java.util.Scanner class, as suggested above.